# Matlab: Having trouble with this code regarding arrays

Tags: matlab

Here is the question:

The file upcs.txt contains a list of UPC codes that were scanned in a grocery
store. Each line should, ideally, contain 12 digits corresponding to a single product. Read
the contents of the file and store the entries into an m x 12 sized numeric array named
codes, where m is the number of valid lines in the le. Lines that have less or more than
12 digits should be discarded. Some lines with 12 digits may have digits that were not
correctly scanned, which were replaced by the letter `X'. These missing digits should be
represented in the array codes by the integer`-1'. After processing the file, print the total
number of lines read, the number of lines discarded, and the number of lines correctly
processed and stored in codes.

upcs.txt:

X9096X082489

921642004330

810905023006

733554287763

413527622XX1

287X35871528

100093334850

764491079X90

1537X8886614

086755751640

860053705316

980098819206

038356338621

577577248178

82825685985

684580785580

736657539753

71113617151

935014271064

702345843488

58316491755

110118383664

333841856254

996003013296

495258095746

4457870230

684104168936

522784039910

6504512835

699553963094

853110488363

554147120089

---

Here is my code so far:

```
fid = fopen('upcs.txt');
mat = [];
if fid == -1
    disp('File open was not successful')
else codes = {};
    while feof(fid) == 0
        aline = fgetl(fid);
        num = strtok(aline);
        codes = [codes; num]
    end;
[m n] = size(codes)
discard = 0
for i = 1:m
    len = length (codes(i))
    if len ~= 12
        codes = [];
        discard = discard + 1
    else
        char(codes(i))
        codes = strrep(codes, 'X', '-1')
    end
end
codes
end
```

The trouble I am having is that I don't know how to delete the codes that have less or more than 12 digits in my code.

Comment: I think there is a end missing, at the first if else statement. Please correct and indent  your code.

Comment: your codes are not correct. In the question, you want 'an m x 12 sized numeric array named codes'. But in your code, 'codes' is a 32*1 cell, not numeric array. Also, in the for-loop, 'len = length (codes(i))' is not correct. Here, len is 1 always.  You should use 'len = length (codes{i})'. Also the 'end' of 'if-else' is placed at the wrong position. Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
clear;clc;
fid = fopen('upcs.txt','r');
if fid == -1
    error('File open was not successful');    
end

C = textscan(fid,'%s');
C = C{1};

all_codes_num = size(C,1);
codes_discarded_num = 0;
codes_missed_digit_num = 0;
codes_correct_num = 0;
codes = [];
for i = 1:all_codes_num
    one_code = C{i};
    if length(one_code) == 12
        x_flag = 0;
        code_tmp = zeros(1,12);
        for j = 1:12
            if one_code(j) == 'X' || one_code(j) == 'x'
                code_tmp(j) = -1;
                x_flag = 1;
            else 
                code_tmp(j) = str2num(one_code(j));
            end
        end
        if x_flag == 1
            codes_missed_digit_num = codes_missed_digit_num +1;
        end
        codes = [codes;code_tmp];
    elseif length(one_code) ~= 12
        codes_discarded_num = codes_discarded_num + 1;
    end
end

all_codes_num
codes_discarded_num
codes_with_x = codes_missed_digit_num
correct_codes_without_x = all_codes_num - codes_discarded_num - codes_with_x
```

codes: have all the correct codes and also 12-length codes with missing data which has been replaced with '-1'. This is a m*12 numeric matrix. Each row is a code.

all_codes_num: the number of all the lines we have read

codes_discarded_num: the number of all the codes which have more or less than 12 chars

codes_with_x: the number of 12-length codes which have missing digits.

correct_codes_without_x: the number of 12-length codes which have digits only.

In the codes, I assume that in the 'upcs.txt', each line is a code.